# Asp.Net Jquery on User control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Trying to validate the text in usercontrol, i am not able to get the value of the text in calling page.

Follwing is the code in aspx page, ucPassengerNameBlock

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblFirstNameResource1" Text="First Name(s)" />*
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="txtFirstNameResource1" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqFirstName" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ForeColor="" ErrorMessage="Enter First Name" CssClass="err_red" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also in user control have a public method for this user control text box

```
  public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            txtFirstName.Text = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
            return txtFirstName.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            txtFirstName.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

In the page, i am trying to read the value

```
 function ValidateNameIput() {

        var textfirstName = $("#<%= FirstName%>").val();
        var a = $('#<%= FirstName %>').val();
            //$("#mainContent_NameBlock1_lblFirstName").text();
        //  alert(label_text);

        var trytext = $("ctl00_mainContent_NameBlock1_txtFirstName").text();


        if (textfirstName == null || textfirstName.trim.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
   }
```

But not able to do.

Comment: Can some one point how can i get the value

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your control through its `ClientID`:

```
var textfirstName = $("#<%= lblFirstName.ClientID %>").val();
```

Comment: used    var textfirstName = $("#<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>").val();       and got The name 'txtFirstName' does not exist in the current context
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) @roland